# Why my maven project cannot import the installed dependency in my vscode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have a maven project:

[image]

the maven settings file is at there `/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6/conf/settings.xml`.

this is the content of maven `settings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6/repository</localRepository>

  <pluginGroups>

  </pluginGroups>


  <proxies>

  </proxies>


  <servers>

  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP. 
      </name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>


  <profiles>

  </profiles>

</settings>
```

in my maven project, the content of `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.markleo.app</groupId>  
    <artifactId>java-oss-upload-demo</artifactId>  
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aliyun.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>aliyun-sdk-oss</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

after I execute `mvn install` success, the depency `aliyun-sdk-oss` be installed at there `/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6/repository/com/aliyun/oss/aliyun-sdk-oss`.

but in my project when I import it in `java-oss-upload-demo/src/main/java/com/markleo/app/Index.java`,

```
package com.markleo.app;

import com.aliyun.oss.ClientException;
import com.aliyun.oss.OSS;
import com.aliyun.oss.OSSClientBuilder;
import com.aliyun.oss.OSSException;
import com.aliyun.oss.model.PutObjectRequest;
import java.io.File;
...
```

I get error:

```
import com.aliyun.oss.ClientException;
                     ^
com/markleo/app/Index.java:4: error: package com.aliyun.oss does not exist
import com.aliyun.oss.OSS;
                     ^
com/markleo/app/Index.java:5: error: package com.aliyun.oss does not exist
import com.aliyun.oss.OSSClientBuilder;
                     ^
com/markleo/app/Index.java:6: error: package com.aliyun.oss does not exist
import com.aliyun.oss.OSSException;
                     ^
```

I do have the package in maven panbel: repository.

[image]

Comment: Based on your configuration you want to prevent your Maven from downloading anything from somewhere using http protocol, now what I don't understand is why do you think you need this configuration in the first place as Maven default repository is Maven Central (already https) as per its documentation: [Downloading from a Remote Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#downloading-from-a-remote-repository)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hi, thanks your response I will optimize it, my requirement is why my project do not use the `aliyun-sdk-oss`.

Comment: One thing to check, does VS code have access to that folder (/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6/repository)?

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a reference to the `aliyun-sdk-oss` package in your maven panel.

[image]

If not, import as follows

[image]

Comment: I do have the dependencies in my maven panel.

Comment: is it in vscode?